# I want to retain the state of selected choices in Alert Dialog MutliChoicesItems in Android?

Tags: android

```
  adLang.setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.Lang, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                adMutiple.add(i);
                String a;
                a = "," + strLang[i];
                txtLang.append(a);
            } else if (adMutiple.contains(i)) {
                adMutiple.remove(Integer.valueOf(i));
            }
        }
    });
```

where adMutliple is an array list , R.array.lang is an string array .

Comment: Store Selection in some local db or pref and when dialog open reload data in it

Comment: As i am Trainee , i cant understand what you have said @HaneetsinghChhabra

Comment: No issue!
look as i understand you want to retain selection when you again open the dilaog so what happen when some thead is executing and you dismiss it. it vanish from memory so everything you selected is vanish for this we store selection information in some where which dont vanish when you dismiss the dilaog so for this read concept of database and shared pref and store selection information in it and when dilaog open again reload info. when you rea the concept you come to know how to do thid. :) keep coding....

Comment: Thanks ,I understand @HaneetsinghChhabra

Comment: i am copying it in answer please accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No issue! look as i understand you want to retain selection when you again open the dilaog so what happen when some thead is executing and you dismiss it. it vanish from memory so everything you selected is vanish for this we store selection information in some where which dont vanish when you dismiss the dilaog so for this read concept of database and shared pref and store selection information in it and when dilaog open again reload info. when you rea the concept you come to know how to do thid. :) keep coding.... –